# AngularJS post fails, jQuery ajax fails too. No CORS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I faced with a strange problem with two customers. Frontend is unable to send POST/GET request insige Angular directive.

Line:

```
xhr.open(method, url, true);
```

Ecception:

```
Exception { message: "", result: 2153644038, name: "", filename: "http://site.ru/scripts/vendor/angular.js", lineNumber: 8327, columnNumber: 0, inner: null, data: null }
```

This is is usual request to the same domain, no CORS.

This problem reproduced only on a customer side (now 2 customers faced this trouble, first Win 8.1 + Firefox Latest and the second Win 7 + Chrome Latest).

**I can't reproduce this problem on my side.** But I see errors on a customers frontends.

Request **from page**: goo[.]gl/T2d2oh
To **API**: "/user/getAds"

Fail callback called in a request:

```
var jqueryRequest = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $scope.url,
    data: JSON.stringify(params),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
    }
});

jqueryRequest.done(function(data, status) {

    /* Do smth */
    $scope.$apply();
});

jqueryRequest.fail(function(jqXHR, status, error) {
    /* Do smth */
    console.error("pagination error", jqXHR, status, error);
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

The same with angular post:

```
$http.post($scope.url, params).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    /* Do smth */
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.error('pagination:error', status, config);
})
```

Exception... "" nsresult: "0x805e0006 ()" location: "JS frame :: http://site.ru/scripts/vendor/angular.js :: createHttpBackend/< :: line 8494" data: no

Comment: It's not a quality question. Please post more codes and what the proper error detail...

Comment: I post more code. But I could not get any error details, only Exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Rename API request patch from "/user/getAds" to "/user/getObjects" to avoid block from **ads blocker** apps.